# Apple iCal on Snow Leopard using exchange, has an alert (count invite). What does that mean?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, calendar.app, exchange

On my Snow Leopard machine, iCal is hooked up to Exchange, and there is a red circle badge/count on my iCal, presumably because of some invite or event. How do I search for what it is, and acknowledge it, and remove the counter, or decrement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely correct: the circle indicates you have received an invitation and it is ready for processing. Look in iCal under notifications, there you can decide what to do with the invitation (see left pane):

[image]

Comment: awesome thanks, simple as that, dont know why its not as intuitive